# I need to scrape all the analytics from a Flurry account

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics

Right now, the only project I can see that does this is

https://github.com/lucamartinetti/flurry-scraper

...but it currently is not logging in properly, I suspect that this is do to the fact that Flurry has made changes to their API which result in the login not working anymore...

I tried messing with it, but am unable to get it to work.

Can anyone help me, or point me in the direction of a project that will do this? I want to scrape all the data possible and download it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
-Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to scrape the website if all you want is analytics metrics of your app and you have the API key.

You just need to access this data using [Flurry's reporting APIs](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/api/).

For instance, you can make a REST call to the [AppMetrics API](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/api/code/appmetrics/) and it would give you data about about your apps' users, sessions, pageviews, etc in XML or JSON. A simple AppMetrics call would be of the form:

```
http://api.flurry.com/appMetrics/METRIC_NAME?apiAccessCode=APIACCESSCODE&apiKey=APIKEY&startDate=STARTDATE&endDate=ENDDATE&country=COUNTRY&versionName=VERSIONNAME&groupBy=GROUPBY
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you mean. This helps a lot. How would I make a Rest call that groups the events by specific user?

Comment: Really want I want to be able to do is pull data for specific phones...if possible.

Comment: @Marcubus In that case, you can create a Flurry event that captures the name of the device type and use the EventMetrics to later pull that data (https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/api/code/eventmetrics/). This will give you grouping by device type (event). You can even add parameters to the events and the EventMetrics will return those parameters.